# Is there a way to transfer Skyrim: Special edition saves from an Xbox One to a flash drive, and vice versa?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

I currently want to make a few changes to one of my Skyrim: Special Edition saves currently located on my Xbox One. Unfortunately, I can only make these changes using some special software on my PC.

Is there a way to transfer my Skyrim: Special Edition Saves from my Xbox One hard drive, to a flash drive, and then back onto my Xbox One hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/33up4s/how_do_i_back_up_my_xbox_one_game_saves_to_a_usb/), this isn't possible.  Instead, with the Xbox One, all saves are backed up to the cloud (which you cannot access in any other way as far I know).  The reasons provided is that this is one way that players can cheat their games by modding their saves (something that I've witnessed first hand with the Xbox 360).  I suspect this is what you may be trying to do (though I'm not accusing you nor do I care).

I did find [a guide](http://www.ibtimes.co.in/transferring-xbox-one-saves-here-are-7-easy-steps-get-you-started-6206860) on how to do this, but it was posted two years ago and it does not appear to be valid anymore. I tested this myself with my console, and at step two, there is no option for pressing Y, and there is nothing in regards to step 3 for transferring saves, only moving the actual game itself to another storage device.

I've explored in My game and Apps and navigated to a save from one of my games, and the only options available are to delete.